# How are Users logged out of Laravel 5.3s Auth implementation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

So I have a Laravel 5.3 application where I decided to add a User Authentication using:

php artisan make:auth

However, after working on programming the registering and logging in of users, I looked around and I don't see a LogoutController of any kind or a logout.blade.php file? So of course after I created the logout link in the side-nav I get this error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218
```

How does one create a proper logout page in Laravel 5.3 using the Auth implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure if anything comes pre-built when you use artisan to make:auth, but until someone pipes up with a more appropriate answer, you can create a route to /logout, and then code the logging out manually with Auth::logout();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its' in vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth

These holde the showloginform function and the logout function. These display the form. Note that these will display only if you have created them with artisan make:auth.

I remember struggling with this to, I don't now exactly where, but I found this in a generated page from laravel:

```
        <li>
            <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                Logout
            </a>
            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/admin/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
        </li>
```

If you add this to your navigation you will logout.

For me it was the admin panel, for you it could be something different.

Note that this is not a logout page, but just a logout link which will log you out. I learned all this just by searching through the laravel classes which are used for the Auth. Poke around a bit and it will make sense.